atd/batch : schedule a task with batch to run after the currently running ones but before the pending ones
I regularly schedule tens or more jobs with atd/batch on my linux box. The sets often take hours, or sometimes days to complete. However, sometimes I want to run a few jobs that shall take about 5-10 minutes to complete, and I would like their results today instead of, say, three days later.
So, I would like to instruct atd to wait for completion of the currently running task, then run this particular jobs and then return to scheduling those that are pending. Running the tasks in parallel is really not an option, they really mess with each other.
